# Is 100% accuracy using randomForest indicative of anything wrong?

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest, overfitting

I am getting a 100% accurate result on randomForest model in R for loan default data even when my training set and test set are completely non-overlapping. I am using abt 8 parameters/features for training the model. The model gives me ntree=1 and mtry=1. Is there anything wrong with 100% accuracy? When I do importance() I get perfectly sensible imprtance values (Ginicoeffs). Also, I am sure I am not feeding in the training data again during the testing phase. But I am surprised to get the 100% fit and the ntree=1 and mtry=1 look slightly doubtworthy. Can someone answer if theres anything wrong or its a posisble scenario?

Comment: The default value for mtry is the rounded down square root of your number of features or number of features /3 depending on wheter you are looking at classification or regression (not familiar with the data).

Comment: If it is that easy to get 100% accuracy you don't need random forest. (Anyway you are using just one fully grown tree) try another simpler model, eg a single decision tree (c4.5) or logistic regression

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the depth of the tree. The issue could be overfitting. If I am correct, the ntree is the number of trees in your forest, and if it is one, this is a single decision-tree. I'd look at the tree and assess for overfitting.